# Alpha numeric generated values fails to insert into a texfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have auto generated alpha numeric values i generate. When i generate its able to pop up in alert, but its not able to insert the values into a textfield

```
function stringGen(len)
{
    var text = " ";

    var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
    text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));

    return text;
    $('#search').val(stringGen(5)); 


}

alert(stringGen(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the function before the last jquery line runs. Try moving it up before the return and just putting text in the .val opposed to calling the function inside of itself.

```
  // define the function
  function stringGen(len)
  {
      var text = " ";

      var charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

      for( var i=0; i < len; i++ )
      text += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length));

      // put the text in the jquery
      $('#search').val(text); 
  }
  // call the function here
  stringGen(5);
```

Comment: nothing happens, the values do not insert into the textfiled. can you create a working fiddle?

Comment: Yah it's because you need to use text instead of val. https://jsfiddle.net/mwe9fz82/